# Raspberry Pi abruptly "dies" when I apply physical pressure

Tags: pi-2, hat, sense-hat

I have been using my Pi B2 since 2015.

I recently got a Sense Hat, but it behaves extremely weirdly when I use it.

For example, I used the mini joystick, which applied slight pressure to my Pi.
Then, suddenly it "died", and:

1. I Lost all my work
2. All windows shut
3. The Pi abruptly powered off without shutting down

This happened multiple times, so I screwed the HAT onto the Pi

But it is still happening...

What can stop this problem, and why does it occur?

Comment: If you have, or can lay hands on, a second Pi, the best place to start would be to confirm that the Hat is responsible for the crash by mounting it on a known good Pi. If the second Pi crashes, the problem's in the Hat. If not, the problem's in the first Pi.

Comment: What surface is the Pi on when you are applying pressure?

Comment: @Steve On a wooden table

Comment: I would try the sense hat on a different Pi. It sounds like you have a bad solder joint or connection somewhere. By using  a second Pi you can determine if it is the Pi or sense hat.